# 'Line2D' object has no property 'line' error when using Matplotlib in a PyQt5 subwindow

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am trying to embed a Matplotlib plot in a PyQt5 subwindow written in Python.  When I plot a line in the plot I get the error:

> 'Line2D' object has no property 'line'

Below is the relevant code extracted from my application.  Any help would be much appreciated and if anyone knows of a better way to do this that would be much appreciated too.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(plotWidth, plotHeight), dpi=dotsPerInch)
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
self.subPlot = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
#xData, yData are lists of data points
self.subPlot.plot(xData, yData, line='b.-', label=lableText)
```

Comment: I've found the cause of this error.  I was including both colour and style information in the line property.  The solution was to input the 'b.-' string without the keyword line.

Answer (score 0):

You should try below as [official site](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) says.

`linestyle='--'`